# Checkbox to update based on another Material checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two material checkboxes and few divs on page like this

```
 <mat-checkbox labelPosition="after"
            (change)="myChangeRequest.budgetChecked=!myChangeRequest.budgetChecked"  >Budget Change
          </mat-checkbox>
          <mat-checkbox labelPosition="after"
            (change)="myChangeRequest.drawdownChecked= !myChangeRequest.drawdownChecked">Drawdown Date
          </mat-checkbox>
```

HTML

The way I  am trying to implement is

When drawdown is checked, budget also needs to get checked automatically if its not. But when someone checking budget it does not affect drawdown. Also when drawdown unchecks it dosnt required to uncheck budget.

So what I did is

```
          <mat-checkbox labelPosition="after"
            (change)="myChangeRequest.drawdownChecked= !myChangeRequest.drawdownChecked;myChangeRequest.budgetChecked=true">Drawdown Date
          </mat-checkbox>
```

Since I'm a newbie with Angular, I'm not sure its good or correct or is it good to use two way binding by [(ngModel)] or is it not work for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A Material (input or checkbox) can be used with [(ngModel)] -or use in a Reactive Forms using formControlName- and, in case of mat-checkbox you can use also (change)

In Angular, in an event you always has as argument `$event`, so you can use some like

```
<mat-checkbox labelPosition="after" [(ngModel)]="myChangeRequest.budgetChecked">
  Budget Change
</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox labelPosition="after" [(ngModel)]="myChangeRequest.drawdownChecked"
     (change)="drawDownChange($event)">Drawdown Date
</mat-checkbox>
```

in .ts you create the function

```
drawDownChange(event:any)
{
    if (event.checked)
         this.myChangeRequest.budgetChecked=true;
}
```

See that, in mat-checkbox, event return an object and the property "checked" is true or false. (you can see in the docs that is an object of type [MatCheckboxChange](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api#MatCheckboxChange). In a normal input `(input)="myFunction($event)"` the argument is the value of the input

NOTE: You can use only the .html in the way

```
<mat-checkbox labelPosition="after" [(ngModel)]="myChangeRequest.drawdownChecked"
     (change)="$event.checked && myChangeRequest.budgetChecked=true">Drawdown Date
</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: That's lovely. But I didn't understand why $event.checked in the (change).

Comment: About $event: If you has a simple input `<input (input)="log($event)"` the "$event" is the value of the input. But when we has a custom form Control or a Component with an `@Output` (see, https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) we can create differents "events", and pass whatever we want.) We can see some complex component, as mat-checkbox, or a ngb-datepicker, or a ... Each developer choose what you can get in $event. Normally in the docs you has an API, if we see the `@Output` we can knowthe type of object we get in $event